# Remove link text in Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` which is populated from a list. I then Have defined a link `column` in the last `column` which is not `DataBound` saying `View`, how do I remove this link text if a condition is met. I have the below:

```
        dgvReport.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvReport.DataSource = queries;

        //locals 
        Int32 lastColumnIndex = this.dgvReport.Columns.Count - 1;

        //hide reads links for the null queries
        for (int i=0; i < queries.Count; i++) {
            if (queries[i].SomeID == null || queries[i].AnotherID == null) {
                this.dgvReport.Rows[i].Cells[lastColumnIndex].Value = "";
            }
        }
```

This is not working and my column text still shows `View`. Any ideas?

**Edit**: lastColumnIndex is 24 which is indeed the last column index

Comment: As an alternative,if the condition is met, then you can set the link button visibility to false.

Comment: Can you verify that your if statement is evaluating to true for any iterations of the loop?

Comment: Yes there are instances where it goes into the loop

Comment: I have overcome this by doing the check in the stored procedure and binding the column to the data. i.e. CASE WHEN someID iS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'View' END [ViewOK]

Comment: I'm having trouble comprehending what you're saying, but if you're saying you solved your own problem then post it as an answer and give it a checkmark :]

Answer (score -1):

You might try

```
View.PlainTextBehaviour = true;
```

It will remove the link and show it as plain text

Comment: Strange, `PlainTextBehaviour` is not a property I know about for datagridview cells.